# Add url segment in specific domain using rewrite rule .htaccess apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have url like this

> mydomain.com

But when I access it, I want rewrite it to this url

> mydomain.com/news

In other case, I want it like this

> mydomain.com/read/1   -> mydomain.com/news/read/1
>
> mydomain.com/view?cat=sport -> mydomain.com/news/view?cat=sport

My code is like this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/news/$1 [QSA,NC]
```

But it still not work. It is not add "news" in next url segment. 
Please suggest how I can write a rewrite rule for this in .htaccess?
I am sorry about my English

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with the following :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !^news /news%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```